# Why this engine can work without a timing belt?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, combustion

[image]

Is it possible that this tiny engine work without timing belt? I have seen the schematics of it and it pretty much rely on holes in the middle of piston to get the hot gas out whereas the ignition is at top of piston.

Comment: Why do you think an engine *needs* a timing belt?

Comment: it is unclear what your question actually is ... what do you not understand about the operation of that engine?

Comment: it works without a timing belt because there's nothing to time.

Comment: @TigerGuy stuff *is* timed by the length and shape of the ports...

Comment: @SolarMike, you & I have a different idea of what timing is.  That's just engine design to me.  Timing means matching components together so they act at the right point in the cycle.

Comment: @TigerGuy so a scallop in the piston crown to open the exhaust port earlier in the cycle ticks the timing box as it happens at so many degrees after TDC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no conventional valves that need to be moved; and no cam. 2-cycle engines have a variety of strange ( to me ) valves ; some like flappers.

Comment: those are `reed valves`

Answer (score -1):

For one thing, it's a diesel engine so there is no need to set a spark relative to piston position.
For another, even when you are dealing with a four-stroke ICE, it's technically possible to have both the ignition timing and the valve timing done electronically.

Comment: diesel injectors have always been timed, and you still have to time the valves.